# Responsive design when page is loaded in iOS app's web view

Tags: ios, uiwebview, responsive-design, media-queries, accessibility

I would like to know if it is possible to adapt the content of a webpage when it's loaded from a specific application's web-view.

I was thinking about media queries but : I want to have a different web design when the page is loaded in the mobile browser or in the app's web view.

Is there anything I can do in order to differentiate them or should I change the user-agent of the webview and differentiate the content this way ?

Comment: Media Queries CAN give a completely different design on mobile as it does on desktop.

Comment: Yes I know, that's not what I'm asking. I want to know if it's possible to differentiate a webview and a mobile browser in the responsive design.

Comment: "web app" view? Or a native app's WebView?

Comment: you can find difference by user agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143763/does-uiwebview-send-the-same-user-agent-in-the-request-headers-as-mobile-safari) has answer for you :

Web requests made from UIWebView will not include the word "Safari" in the User Agent string. Web requests made from Mobile Safari will. This is the best way I have found for determining of a request is coming from within an app or from Mobile Safari.

Sample User Agent from

```
UIWebView within app: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile
```

Sample User Agent from Mobile Safari:

`User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make web page responsive from UIWebview,there is only one way is the use media queries for making responsive site. You cant change from your native app.