# Trigger.io: Change Name of the forge.tabs.openWithOptions()

Tags: iphone, facebook, tabs, trigger.io

We are using `forge.tabs.openWithOptions()` when we open the login dialog of Facebook.

The problem is when Facebook will email to the user (if users has turned on notification security).

It says `Facebook Login from "UIWebView on Iphone"`

[image]

Is there any way to change that label?

Waiting for your reply, Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using the Facebook module to use the native Facebook SDK integration: https://trigger.io/modules/facebook/current/

Comment: @AmirNathoo, We are using Native Facebook Module from trigger.io, Though the module is working properly, the problem is the User Agent that facebook emailed to the user is "UIWebView" since if I understand it correctly, `Forge.tabs` is just using the native webview, Is it possible to override the User-agent that instead of it, we can use e.g. the title we set to the `forge.tabs` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not possible. Facebook seems to be using the user agent string to determine the label. From my experimentation I have replaced the user-agent string with the Mobile Safari user-agent string and the email had "Mobile Safari on iPhone". When I replaced the user-agent string with a custom string I get "Facebook login from an unrecognized device‏".

See [Does UIWebView send the same User-Agent in the Request Headers as mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143763/does-uiwebview-send-the-same-user-agent-in-the-request-headers-as-mobile-safari) for more information on the User-Agent strings for UIWebView and Mobile Safari.